# colnames() cannot be used in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems that the following code doesn't work

```
data("iris")
dplyr::select(iris, colnames(iris)!= "Species")
```

Is it because `colnames()` cannot be used at the same with `dplyr()` package but only r base package

Does that mean we can only use

```
dplyr::select(iris, -5)
```

Comment: `dplyr::select(iris, -Species)`

Comment: We cannot use ```colnames()```?

Comment: `dplyr::select(iris, -Species)` will also work.  This is [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) in action.

Comment: `colnames(iris) == "Species"` will return a logical vector output which is not we want for `select`

Comment: good point @AnilGoyal

Comment: you can thus use `dplyr::select(iris, colnames(iris)[colnames(iris)!= "Species"])`

Comment: I got this @AnilGoyal you are talented :P

Comment: Please study the [help text of `select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could still use `setdiff`

```
dplyr::select(iris, setdiff(names(iris), "Species"))
```

Or wrap with `which` to get the postiion index

```
dplyr::select(iris, which(colnames(iris)!= "Species"))
```

---

Or we can simply negate (`!`)

```
dplyr::select(iris, !Species)
```

Comment: I got it. For the code ```iris_selected<-iris[ , colnames(iris)!="Species"``` it seems we don't need ```which()``` I got confused with the ```dplyr```package now lol :p

Comment: @MathildaFang that is base R `?Extract` syntax where you can pass either column names or index or logical.  In `select`, there are some other happening behind the hood if you look at the source code